# How can I sufficiently determine minima of a function with matrices and vectors?

Tags: real-analysis, matrices, derivatives, optimization

To determine the coefficients of a regression function I use the method of least squares ($\text{KQ}$). For this I look for a minimum of the following function. $X$ is a matrix, $y$ and $\beta$ are vectors. The elements of these variables are always real numbers:

$$\text{KQ}(\beta) = y^\top y-2\beta^T(X^\top y)+\beta^T(X^\top X)\beta$$

I have already made the first derivation:
$$\frac{ \delta \text{KQ}(\beta) }{ \delta\beta  } = -2X^\top y+2X^\top X\beta$$

Rearranging for $\beta$, we obtain $$\beta = (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top y.$$ For a singular matrix $X$ following term:
$$\beta = (X^\top X)^{-1}X^\top y.$$

How can I now show that I have found a minimum? With the first derivative I find extremes, but they could also be maxima. Can I present a proof using the second derivative?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second derivative $\text{KQ}_{\beta\beta}=2X^\top X$ is a positive semi-definite matrix so the minimum is attained.